# How do I assign specific permissions to groups in AD for different applications?

Tags: active-directory

The question might sound a bit vague, but I wasn't sure how else to word it. I've had little experience with AD but people have always explained it similarly to how you apply folder permissions but that still doesn't answer the question for me. To put it into some context, how would I restrict a certain group to say deploy workstations in SCCM and another to only deploy applications. Or another example would be a group with only Read permissions when using Microsoft Visio and another group with read and write permissions

Comment: You have to think of it in the reverse: the permissions aren't set on the group, they're set in the application. Just like with folders, you don't open the group in AD and grant the group permissions to a folder. Instead, you go to the folder and add the group to the permissions. You're modifying the folder, not the group. So you have to look up how to do it for each case, since doing what you want in Visio will be completely different than SCCM, etc.

Comment: Hey @Fergus Long, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   Every application that requires the services of Active Directory must integrate with AD, i.e., open the required **LDAP and Kerberos protocol ports** with respect to **inbound and outbound communication** to happen with AD for that application. Once done, then ensure that the application uses LDAP authentication for retrieving the details required for authorized and validated response from a Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) server, in this case, Active Directory Server.

•   Then, when you configure the access for the API of that application, ensure that the required groups and users are selected for access to that application. Like for example, if you want certain groups of your AD environment to have access to your Anti-virus software server, then you will have to configure the same in that application’s Master server or EPO Server. Thus, as you said, in case of SCCM, if want to allow only a certain group of users to deploy workstations in SCCM and another to deploy applications through it, then you will create a custom security role in Security  Administration workspace of SCCM console wherein the required role will be created and accordingly permissions will be set for those IDs regarding the role they need to perform.

•   Thus, SCCM has inbuilt functionality to grant specific permissions relating to the various tasks that it supports according to which roles are created. Hence, permissions for different groups in Active Directory depend on those applications which want to integrate with AD and its authentication mechanism.